# XML file keeps changing, how can I detect changes? What values/nodes were changed and get new values?

Tags: java, xml, servlets, service, io

I'm watching changes in an XML file which keeps on updating every less than a second or more. Updates are being done by an external service.

Is there a way to detect the changes on this XML file and make a java function that will return what node was changed and what's the new value of the particular changed node?

Thank you for the help.

Comment: This doesn't seem like a good fit for a Java solution. Do you actually have to check on every update?

Comment: I think XML is not a good solution for this at all. Seems to me that you have an XML file on a shared drive or so which is concurrently updated by different clients.

Comment: "updating every less than a second or more". Is the updater of the file doing so in an atomic manner, or is a lock being used to synchronize updates. Because if neither is so it seems that your reader program could read an invalid XML file. That would make *any* solution difficult.

Comment: Thanks.Yes, it's XML file in a shared drive being updated by windows service.My goal is to determine what has changed in each update.Is it possible and practical?All I want is to get what node or property was changed and use it in some purpose.

Answer (score 1):

For watching the actual FILE change you could use NIO.2 (java 7)

http://blogs.oracle.com/thejavatutorials/entry/watching_a_directory_for_changes

After each change you can compare the old XML against the new one.
Tools for diffing xml you can find here:

http://www.manageability.org/blog/stuff/open-source-xml-diff-in-java

Comment: Yap, I have a file watching algorithm already.The comparing API you suggested must also work, but one question though. How can I compare previous and current xml which is updating every second? I'm thinking of storing previous document in class variable and comparing it to current xml. Thanks for any suggestion. –

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried this extension but may be the version extension of the XML-DB eXist can help you with your requirement. http://exist.sourceforge.net/versioning.html
Though to use this you are required to store the changed documents in the DB each.

Comment: Thanks! Do you think this is practical for an xml being updated every less than a second?

Comment: Sorry I have no experience about documents being updated that often :/